# Qtの商用ライセンスを購入すると、特典はどれほどのものなのか？

Tags: qt, ライセンス, pyside, pyqt

以前、[PySideで開発したもののそのあとどうすればいいかわからない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41245/pyside%E3%81%A7%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%82%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)で質問をしました。
私は主体の取り違えを起こしていました。商用ライセンスは、開発者が定めてもいいにも関わらず、私は、購入しなければいけないものだと思っていたのです。購入をして、初めて自分の作品でお金とっていいですよ。という感じ。商売用ライセンスだと思っていたのです。しかし、[こうした](https://www.qt.io/download#section-3)購入する商用ライセンスというものもあるわけで、以前の解答と合わせて考えると、どうやら、Qt開発者が、自分の開発したライブラリであるQtの商用ライセンスを購入したらこういう特典があるよという話だったようです。

### Q1.

例えば、こういうQtの特典を商用ライセンス購入によって得た場合、このSOFで質問しても解決できないような、みなさんがお知りにならないような疑問も、サポートしてもらえるものなのでしょうか？

> The Qt Company’s expert support team helps you solve your development challenges.

と書いてあります。Qtについては、以前からあまり盛んでないものを対象とした質問を出していますが、どうにも解答が付かなくて、何らかの手段がないものか探していました。
　
それと、ライセンスについて、以前お聞きしたものの、整理がつかなくなってしまったのです。

- [QtのLGPL版について](http://qt-log.open-memo.net/sub/other--about-Qt-LGPL.html)
  私が過去主体を取り違えたときに読んだものがここです。
- [Qtのライセンスについての考察](https://philosy.com/blog/2009/12/09/qt-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E8%80%83%E5%AF%9F/)
  これがわかりやすかったかも。
- [緑之庵](http://blog.hermit4.info/2012/07/qt.html)

私の製品について、商用ライセンスを発行するのは私なのでしょう。しかし、いったい何を守って何を守らなくてもいいのやら、正直混乱してしまいました。
簡単に言えば、お上の目を恐れているということです。

### Q2.

1. 自分で開発した製品について商用ライセンスを発行するのは開発者
2. 自分で定めた料金を設定し、自由に商売してもよい。
3. `LGPL`版Qtで開発したものは、ソースコードの開示は強制されない。しかし、一度公開したら、その後の改変したコードも公開する必要がある。
4. `GPL`版Qtで開発したものは、ソースコードの開示は強制される。
5. `Qt`の商用ライセンスを購入するというのは、商売するライセンスをもらえるというのではなくて、上のサイトを信頼する限り、GPLの制限が解除され、コードの非公開が可能となる。非公開での改変もOKリバースエンジニアリングの禁止もできる。また、開発にあたっての様々なサポートが得られる。という程度の意味なのですね。

上記のようなとらえ方であっていますか？

Q1では、商用ライセンスのサポートはどれほどのものなのか？
具体的には、[以前の質問１](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41438/qt%E7%B3%BB%E3%81%A7word%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%BF%E5%85%A5%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)[以前の質問２](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41358/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E3%81%AE%E5%BD%B1%E9%9F%BF%E3%82%92%E5%8F%97%E3%81%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84gui%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)[以前の質問３](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38082/qabstracttextdocumentlayout-reimplementation-%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AF-subclass%E5%8C%96)等、まだ未解決の問題についても、答えてくれそうなサポートなのか？
Q2では、以上のような理解で漏れはないのか？

ライセンスについてちょっと慎重に行きたいと思っていますので、Q1が最もお聞きしたいことなのですが、Q2も併せて伺いたいと思います。私は`GPL`より`LGPL`のがよさそうだぞと思って、`PySide`を選んで進んできました。`C++ Qt`と、`PyQt`,`PySide`は、名前は違えど、根底にある理解は一致しているので、`Qt`の商用ライセンス等でも、全く受けられるサポートには違いはないと思っています。`C++`のコードで教えられたら何とか行ける程度ですが。

Comment: Q2を少し編集しました。意図通りでない場合は訂正願います。

Comment: [https://ja.osdn.net/projects/ossdirectory/wiki/product_Qt]ここを見ると、最高100万を超えるようです。脱皮します。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ちょうど今日、Qtブログにサポート関連の記事が投稿されました。
[Qt Premium Support: Learning and Experiences](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/02/05/premium-support-learning-and-experiences/)
一度読まれることをお勧めします。

なお、GPL / LGPLが議論されていますが、**GPL /LGPLを適用したアプリケーション** と **GPL /LGPLを適用したライブラリにリンクした非GPL /LGPLアプリケーション** とでは全く状況が異なります。商用を検討されているとのことですので、後者が前提にあると理解しました。

[LGPLに対する動的リンクの誤解](http://atmarksharp.v01.jp/posts/lgpl-dynamic-link.html)が参考になります。
LGPL版Qtを使用した場合、作成されたアプリケーションはGPL / LGPLを適用する必要はありません。ソースコードの非公開、アプリケーションの複製不可等の制限を加えることができます。ただし、LGPL版Qt部分には及びません。とはいえLGPL版Qtの入手方法を提示するだけで十分です。

GPL版Qtを使用した場合、作成されたアプリケーションはGPL相当が要求されます。入手者（購入者）に対し、複製を禁ずることはできず、アプリケーションのソースコード開示も求められます。

Answer (score 5):

まず、質問を拝見した感想を記載します:

- Qt社のサポートに問い合わせた方が適切な回答が得られるかと思います。Qt社にとってはFAQだと思いますので妥当な回答は用意済みなのではないでしょうか。

  - [About Us](https://www1.qt.io/company/)/[Contact Us](https://www1.qt.io/contact-us/)を見る限り日本にも営業拠点はあるようですので日本語の問い合わせ対応も期待できます。
- ここスタックオーバーフローのような技術者向けQ&Aサイトは、ソフトウェア(等)エンジニアリングについてのスペシャリストは多く集まっているかもしれませんが、法律についてのスペシャリストは居たとしてもごく少数だと思います。そのような状況下で、たとえそれらしい回答が得られたとしても、その回答が法律的に見て正しいのかどうか判断できないのではないかと危惧します。

---

上記を述べてから回答を記載するのは非常に蛇足な気持ちにもなるのですが…

---

世の中のソフトウェアは2種類に大別できます。
**私が作ったソフトウェア**か、**私ではない別の誰かが作ったソフトウェア**です。

**私が作ったソフトウェア**:
私がそのソフトウェアの著作者です。
著作者なのでそのソフトウェアを自由にコントロールできます。
お金を支払えば利用しても良い、とするという取り決めにすることも出来ますし、リバースエンジニアを禁止することも出来ます。
(利用条件を設定し利用許諾を与えることを「ライセンスを提供する」と表現したりもします)

**私ではない別の誰かが作ったソフトウェア**:
私はそのソフトウェアの著作者ではありません。
著作者ではないのでそのソフトウェアを自由にコントロールできません。
著作者が、利用したいのであればお金を支払えと言うのであれば、利用するためにお金を支払う必要があります。
(お金を払って使用許諾を受けることを「ライセンスを購入する」と表現したりもします)

**Qtを利用していようが利用していまいが、私が作ったソフトウェアであれば著作者は私**です。したがって私の好きな通りにコントロールできます。
ただし、Qtを利用したのであればQtの利用許諾に同意しているはずであり、そこに書かれている制約には従う必要があります。LGPLに従えと書いてあるのであればもちろんLGPLに従う必要があります。
(見方によっては、他者著作物(今回の場合Qt)を利用することによって、本来著作者である私がコントロールできることに対し制約が課せられ不自由さを押し付けられる、と言うこともできます。)

Qtの場合は2種類の使用許諾が存在し、それぞれ異なる制約を課せられます。
ですので利用するにあたっては、私にとって都合の良い制約の方を選択することになります。

---

> Q1.
>   例えば、こういうQtの特典を商用ライセンス購入によって得た場合、このSOFで質問しても解決できないような、みなさんがお知りにならないような疑問も、サポートしてもらえるものなのでしょうか？

[Qt Support](https://www.qt.io/qt-support/)では2種類のサポートについて説明があります。
Qtに対する一般的なサポートはライセンス購入代金に含まれるようですが、"Support on using Qt for your specific project"に該当するようなものについては追加のサポート費用が発生するのでしょう。
Haruさんの質問の範囲で言うと、PySideが絡むものは標準サポート外ではないか(プレミアムサポートが必要ではないか)、と思われます。

> Q2.
>   1.自分で開発した製品について商用ライセンスを発行するのは開発者
>   2.自分で定めた料金を設定し、自由に商売してもよい。

その通りだと思います。

> 3.LGPLのライセンスで開発したものは、ソースコードの開示は強制されない。しかし、一度公開したら、その後の改変したコードも公開する必要がある。

これは私の理解とは異なります。が、私もLGPLに詳しいわけではないので回答は控えます。
(どこかでそのように解説されていた、ということであれば所在が知りたいです)

> 4.GPLだと、ソースコードの開示は強制される。

ニュアンスとしては合っていると思います。

> 5.Qtの商用ライセンスを購入するというのは、商売するライセンスをもらえるというのではなくて、上のサイトを信頼する限り、GPLの制限が解除され、コードの非公開が可能となる。非公開での改変もOKリバースエンジニアリングの禁止もできる。また、開発にあたっての様々なサポートが得られる。という程度の意味なのですね。

一般的にはそういう理解で良いかと思いますが、これは利用許諾設定者(今回の場合Qt社)に尋ねるべき質問で、第三者が回答できる類いのものではないです。

開発ライセンスと配布ライセンスがわかれている製品もあります。
(商売を行う、つまり利用者にアプリケーションを販売し配布する場合には配布数に応じたライセンス購入が別途必要なものもある、ということです。Qtがそれに該当するかは分かりません。)

Answer (score 1):

正直この手のライセンスの話は提供者に直接聞くしかないのですが（第三者の説明は誤っているかもしれないし、そもそも責任も義務もないし）
https://www.sra.co.jp/qt/licence/index.html
によると Qt の商用版ライセンスを購入すると Q2. 中にある 1.-5. の理解であってそうです。

Q1. のほうですが、要するによくわからないところを教えてくれ、というサポートですよね？
Microsoft においては「サポートは受けられるが有償」です。あなたのプログラムが動かない原因がマイクロソフトの側にある（要するに Windows のバグ）場合には結果的に無料となりますが、そもそもそのような問い合わせをするには有料のサポート契約が必要です。
Qt でどうだかは SRA に問い合わせたほうが早そうです。

http://qt-users.jp/
Qt ユーザー会で mailing list もあります。わからないところを投げてみれば詳しい人がフォローしてくれるかもしれません。サポートではないので必ずコメントがつくとは限りませんけど。